# MySQL: Query to merge

Tags: mysql

had a table with ID, Items, Coffee,Brewer,Tea,Milk

already pulled ID and Items from other table and i could update the Item_1 to 4 using Items column using case statements

the output looks

```
ID   Item_ID   Items    Coffee    Brewer     Tea    Milk
 1    101      Coffee     1          0        0       0
 1    102      Brewer     0          1        0       0
 2    103      Tea        0          0        1       0
 3    104      Milk       0          0        0       1
```

Required Output: I want to have 1's based on ID, like 1st two records has coffee and Brewer both should contain 1's

```
ID   Item_ID   Items    Coffee    Brewer     Tea    Milk
 1    101      Coffee     1          1        0       0  /* Note Brewer value*/
 1    102      Brewer     1          1        0       0
 2    103      Tea        0          0        1       0
 3    104      Milk       0          0        0       1
```

Query

```
  insert into All_Items select distinct ID, Item_ID, Items from temp;

  Update All_Items 
  SET  coffee = case 
     when Items = 'Coffee' Then '1' else '0' end,
     Brewer= case 
       when Items = 'Brewer' Then '1' else '0' end,
       Tea= case 
         when Items = 'Tea' Then '1' else '0' end,
         Milk= case 
           when Items = 'Milk' Then '1' else '0' end;
```

Comment: What logic are you using to populate the table?  also what is your query

Comment: please show the query which u have made so far!!

Comment: @NoobEditor great name

Comment: @MarshallTigerus : haha..trying to catch up the naming convention trend of community....thankx fella..u r d 1st one to appreciate!! :D

Comment: added my queries till now

Comment: @NoobEditor Do try and use full words, especially if you're intending to be an editor. This isn't text messaging and abbreviations can be confusing for those that don't speak English very well.

Comment: @tadman : certainly...would keep that in mind!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you :

```
 Update All_Items 
 set  coffee = case when Items = 'Coffee' Or id in (select * from (select id from All_Items where items = 'Coffee')t) Then '1' else '0' end,
 Brewer= case when Items = 'Brewer' Or id in (select * from (select id from All_Items where items = 'Brewer')t) Then '1' else '0' end,
 Tea= case when Items = 'Tea' Or id in (select * from (select id from All_Items where items = 'Tea')t)  Then '1' else '0' end,
 Milk= case when Items = 'Milk' Or id in (select * from (select id from All_Items where items = 'Milk')t)  Then '1' else '0' end;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7b9e/1)

EDIT:

you could get two tables  and make your table like that:

All_Items  Table

```
  itemID     Coffee    Brewer     Tea    Milk
  1           1          1        0       0
  2           0          0        1       0
  3           0          0        0       1
```

items Table

```
  ID   Item_ID 
  1    101
  1    102
  2    103
  3    104
```

> WHERE All_Items.itemID = items.ID

and like that you can update easily your table by setting 1 to sepecific column by item_id

Comment: Thanks echo_Me...Is it achievable by joins or any other way,becoz i got million records to update.

Comment: Thanks but that will not achieve my requirement. becoz i need all Item_ID's and i don't want to get rid of 101 too....